ERROR: Error during SonarScanner Docker execution
I've installed and ran Soanrqube and Sonarscanner in my Ubuntu 22 vm as containers.
Below is my docker-compose file for starting and running the containers
version: '3.8'

services:
  sonarqube:
    image: sonarqube:community
    container_name: sonarqube
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    environment:
      SONAR_JDBC_URL: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/sonar
      SONAR_JDBC_USERNAME: sonar
      SONAR_JDBC_PASSWORD: sonar
      TZ: UTC
    volumes:
      - sonarqube_data:/opt/sonarqube/data
      - sonarqube_extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions
      - sonarqube_logs:/opt/sonarqube/logs
    networks:
      - sonarnet
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    container_name: sonarqube-db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: sonar
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: sonar
      POSTGRES_DB: sonar
    volumes:
      - postgresql_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - sonarnet

  sonarscanner:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-sonarscanner
    container_name: sonarscanner
    environment:
      SONAR_HOST_URL: http://sonarqube:9000
    networks:
      - sonarnet
    volumes:
      - ./src:/usr/src  # Mount your source code directory here

networks:
  sonarnet:

volumes:
  sonarqube_data:
  sonarqube_extensions:
  sonarqube_logs:
  postgresql_data:

I ran the containers and I'm able to login into Sonarqube UI.
Here are the environment details
Docker Image Name: sonarqube:community
Ports: 9000
Java version: openjdk 17.0.10 2024-01-16
openjdk 17.0.10 2024-01-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+7-Ubuntu-122.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.10+7-Ubuntu-122.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)

When I run the below command, I'm getting the error
sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectKey=demo-project -Dsonar.sources=. -Dsonar.host.url=http://<ipaddress>:9000 -Dsonar.token=sqp_mytoken 

The below is the error I got
ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonar/batch/bootstrapper/EnvironmentInformation has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedClassloader.loadClass(IsolatedClassloader.java:82)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.DefaultBatchFactory.createBatch(DefaultBatchFactory.java:32)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:189)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:138)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:126)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:81)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:62)


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Instead, [edit] your question to include the code as properly formatted text.
